# Why has my question been put on-hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold

I recently asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970467/how-can-i-display-compilation-errors-in-the-vs2013-editor) that has been down-voted and put on-hold as primarily opinion-based. I would like to appeal that decision.

I think the question should be reopened because

- It is not opinion-based; I clearly ask if it is possible (and if yes, how can I do it) to use a software development tool in a certain way.
- It is about a software tool commonly used by programmers (Visual Studio), which makes it on-topic, as described in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

What do you think? Is the reason for putting my question on-hold valid? Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will not *like* [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970467/displaying-c-compilation-errors-in-the-vs-2013-editor#comment36931712_23970467) to the question, but it is certainly answerable. It is not off-topic, certainly not "opinion-based", and probably should not have been closed.

I have edited the question slightly to clean it up, and cast a vote to re-open.

More generally: there is nothing wrong with questions where the answer is "no". The asker rarely likes to *get* that answer, and there is often a lot of resistance directed at the people who post such an answer. It is rare that such answers ever get accepted, save for the rare case where the asker finally throws up her hands and abandons hope. As a result, people don't tend to invest a lot of time in posting answers like this. There has even been some debate about whether "no" is a valid answer (although I think that's nonsensical).

In this specific case, you can see some of that playing out in the comments. Two different people (Hans Passant and Tony Hopkinson) suggest to you that suggestions and feature requests should be directed to the Visual Studio team at Microsoft. Of course, that is good advice, but like you commented, you are not making a feature request—you are taking a necessary preliminary step, asking whether it is even possible.

I should also point out that a "no" answer could include a link to your feature request, if you do decide to submit one. That would also make it useful to future visitors, who could support your feature request if they would also like to see this.

Comment: There are of course an infinite number of possible questions of the form "can visual studio do x" where the answer is "no". Not sure how useful these are on SO though the close reason selected doesn't fit.

Comment: @Martin Sure, there are an infinite number of possible questions of *any* form. This isn't a problem specific to Visual Studio, or even to programming. I'm not sure what we do about it, we can't close all of the questions. And I'm not even sure why that's a problem, since they can just be answered.

Comment: I think a "no" answer in this case is definitely of value to future visitors, even without a feature request link (althought such a link would make it more valuable). This seems like a feature I would expect Visual Studio to have, so when I search on "How do I ... in Visual Studio", finding a quick "You can't!" saves me quite some time. (A feature request link would serve as an excellent definitive reference)

Comment: @HugoRune I agree. I think that questions that can be answered with an obvious and quick "no" can be of help to newbies just starting out with programming or a certain tool (such as myself).

Comment: @CodyGray I think that it's hard to accept "no" (i.e., to actually mark the answer as accepted) on some questions, because it claims much more.  Someone saying "yes, this can be done, here's the way" is actually saying "yes, this can be done, and here's *a* way," and rarely provides proof that there's absolutely no other way.  It's generally harder to prove that "no, there's absolutely no way to do this", so it's harder as an asker to be confident in marking it as accepted.

Comment: For those interested in pursuing this meta-meta discussion: [Can one prove a negative existential claim?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/3680), [Does a negative claimant have a burden of proof?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/678) :-)

Comment: I'm a bit surprised to see everybody here concerned about "no"-answers. Of course a "no" is a useful answer if it can save your time by pointing to a useful alternative. Also, why should a negative claim be difficult to prove? There are plenty of credible references stating that Javascript regular expressions do not support lookbehind. If someone asks for help to write a lookbehind clause in Javascript, point them to that reference and give them a hint, how their problem could be solved in a different way.

Comment: There was actually a podcast in which Jeff Atwood stated that stack overflow should be the first google result which either provides the answer or says that it is not possible. Must be one of the first podcasts.

Comment: The only conceivable problem with "no" answers is that they are more likely to get "stale". If a future version of JavaScript started supporting lookbehind in regular expressions, the answers that said it couldn't would be obsolete. And then we get into the classic problem of keeping all the millions of answers updated over the long term. This is not a problem that is unique to "no" answers, it is just exacerbated by the inevitably of feature creep. For my part, I am all for "no" answers; I post lots of them. I'm just reporting on the backlash I see.

Comment: @GOTO0 The problem with "no" answers is that features that don't exist rarely have official documentation to point to that says they don't exist. So it is difficult to answer with anything much else than an assertion that it is not possible as far as you know.

Answer (score 2):

It was a much longer question when it came up in the close review queue, it's far clearer after the edits. Like Cody Gray I don't think you are going to like the answer anymore than you did the close vote, and I'm still not seeing it as a question with any real value. I'll vote to re-open though and we'll see what greater minds than I think.